# Why is my prolog program stucked in endless recursion

Tags: prolog, logic, swi-prolog

I have the following experimental code

```
s(a,b).
s(b,c).
s(c,b).
r(a).
r(c).
r(d).
p(X,Y) :- s(X,Y), not(r(Y)).
q(X,Y) :- q(Y,X), r(X).
q(X,Y) :- p(Y,X), s(X,Y).
t(X,Y) :- r(X), q(X,Y).
```

Querying for `t(X,Y)` will result in a endless recursion blowing up the stack. But I can actually think of `X=c,Y=b` being the solution because

```
t(c,b) <- r(c), q(c,b)
q(c,b) <- q(b,c), r(c)
q(b,c) <- p(c,b), s(b,c)
p(c,b) <- s(c,b), not(r(b))
```

Can someone explain to me, why prolog doesn't come to this solution and gets caught in an endless recursion around `q(c,b) and q(b,c)`

Many thanks!

Comment: Just by looking at the code:  this bit will be stuck: q(X,Y) :- q(Y,X)
Trace through the code, to see: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SWI-Prolog, you can solve the problem using **tabled execution**.

```
:- table q/2.

s(a,b).
s(b,c).
s(c,b).
r(a).
r(c).
r(d).
p(X,Y) :- s(X,Y), not(r(Y)).
q(X,Y) :- q(Y,X), r(X).
q(X,Y) :- p(Y,X), s(X,Y).
t(X,Y) :- r(X), q(X,Y).
```

Examples:

```
?- t(X,Y).
X = c,
Y = b ;
false.

?- q(X,Y).
X = c,
Y = b ;
X = b,
Y = c.
```

Comment: uh, yes this cuts the recursion. Many thanks!